# Segmentation fault with gcc while accessing global array in local method in C

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault with gcc in below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NT 1000
int arr[NT][6];
int N;

int countifinrange(int i,int max)

    {
        int j=0;
        int icount  = 0;
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        if((arr[j][i]<=max)&&(max<=arr[j][i+1]))
            icount++;
        return icount; 
    }

int main (void)
{
    int i, j, value, l, L;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    scanf("%d",&L);  

          for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<6;j++)
                 {  
                     scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
                 }
         }
     int count;
    for(l=0;l<L;l++)
    for(i=0;i<6;i=i+2)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
             {
                  value = arr[j][i];
                   count=countifinrange(j,value);
              } 
     }
     return 0;
}
```

and with below code:

```
int countifinrange(int i,int max)

    {
        int j=0;
        int icount  = 0;
        int ij = 0;
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            ij = arr[j][i];
        //if((arr[j][i]<=max)&&(max<=arr[j][i+1]))
            icount++;
        }
}
```

The below code works fine:

```
int countifinrange(int i,int max)

    {
        int j=0;
        int icount  = 0;
        int ij = 0;
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                arr[j][i];
                //if((arr[j][i]<=max)&&(max<=arr[j][i+1]))
                icount++;
            }
    }

int main (void)
{
    int i, j, value; 
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
             for(j=0;j<6;j++)
                 {  
                     scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
                 }
         }
     int count; 

    for(i=0;i<6;i=i+2)
        {
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                      value = arr[j][i];
                      count=countifinrange(j,value);
                 }
         }
         return 0;
   }
```

The code works fine in visual studio but gives segmentation fault with gcc-4.6.3.
Can I not access global array inside local method in c, gcc

Comment: What is `N`?...

Comment: `The below code works fine:` how works? not even compile it.

Comment: Most likely you are calling the function with i=5, and when you look for arr[NT,i+1], it runs off the end of the array, causing the seg fault.  Perhaps visual studio has a different memory layout, so that you end up accessing garbage there instead of getting the seg fault.

Comment: N Is another global Variable of type int . Its value is taken using Scanf in main

Comment: What is your input for N ?

Comment: Here's a thought - if you manage to compile it, you could run it with some simple test data and use a debugger, (or printf's) to find out which line generates the fault and what the indices are at the time.

Comment: @user4057066: format your code correctly.

Comment: What is your input for N ??

Answer (score 0):

Just look at your code... the inner dimension of the 2D array is 6 items wide. Yet you increase the value of icount N times, whatever N is. I bet it is a number larger than 6, so you access `arr` out of bounds.

This invokes undefined behavior. The reason it doesn't crash on Visual Studio is just misfortune: "it seems to work" is one form of undefined behavior.

Comment: The value of outer is increased N times. This method is called from a for loop of 6

Comment: @user4057066 Then you need to update your question with code that compiles and can be used to reproduce the error. Because nobody can answer it as it currently stands.